# Set<Integer> inside Map

Tags: java

I have a question. First, I declared a map:

```
Map<TwoIntClass, Set<Integer>> m = new HashMap<TwoIntClass, Set<Integer>>();
```

Now, I want to put stuff inside this map, something like

```
int num = 7;
m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), ?? how to put num inside Set ??);
```

My question is, how do I put variable num inside Set.
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds oddly over complicated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867333/setinteger-inside-map/3867372#3867372) and others have suggested, you need to instantiate a concrete instance of the `Set` interface (like `HashSet`), add your `int` values in the `Set` and then put the `Set` into your `Map`. However, if you are using a custom class for your `Map`'s key, I would suggest you implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method of your `TwoIntClass` class to be sure that you are not creating duplicate entries inside your `Map`. For example, consider this class :

```
public class TwoIntClass {

    private int i1;
    private int i2;

    public TwoIntClass(int i1, int i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;   
    }

    static public void main(String...args) {

        Map<TwoIntClass, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<TwoIntClass, Set<Integer>>();

        Set<Integer> dataset = new HashSet<Integer>();
        dataset.add(1);
        dataset.add(2);

        TwoIntClass i1 = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);
        TwoIntClass i2 = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);

        map.put(i1, dataset);
        map.put(i2, dataset);

        System.out.println( i1.hashCode() + " = " + i2.hashCode() + " == " + i2.equals(i2) + " > map count = " + map.size() );

        TwoIntClass i3 = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);
        System.out.println("Looking for TwoIntClass(5,3)... " + map.containsKey(i3) );

    }
}
```

The output for executing it is :

> 1476323068 = 535746438 == false > map
>   count = 2
>
> Looking for TwoIntClass(5,3)... false

As you see, they both are "equal" (i.e. they both are constructed with the same integers), but they are distinct objects with different hash codes, therefore create two entries in the map. This could lead into possible data corruption in your application. Moreover, executing this line : `map.get(new TwoIntClass(5,3)).add(3);` will generate a `NullPointerException` because the key (it's hash) does not exist in the map. So, you need to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to fix this, so any `TwoIntClass` constructed with the same integers will be considered equal. Something like :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof TwoIntClass)) {
        return false;
    }
    TwoIntClass other = (TwoIntClass) obj;

    return (other.i1 == this.i1) && (other.i2 == this.i2); 
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    //return TwoIntClass.class.hashCode() | i1 | (i2 << 16);

    // better implementation based on the String class
    int hash = TwoIntClass.class.hashCode();

    hash = (hash * 31) + i1;
    hash = (hash * 31) + i2;

    return hash;
}
```

yields a more expected result of

> 1476323071 = 1476323071 == true > map count = 1
>
> Looking for TwoIntClass(5,3)... true

Of course, this `hashCode()` method is <del>over</del> simplistic and you may need to find a yet [better construct](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html), but the bottom line is that implementing them is what I would recommend.

Comment: Why do you assume that his `TwoIntClass` doesn't have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation? Of course the map won't work properly without that, but he didn't ask about that or give code for the key class so I wouldn't just assume he had that wrong. Your `hashCode` method seems a little strange too, as it doesn't follow the general pattern I've seen for hash codes for simple classes like this.

Comment: the code was just a proof of concept. And I assumed that the TwoIntClass didn't have such method overridden simply because of the nature of the question itself. I may be wrong and the OP may already have implemented the methods, but nobody even noted that fact, which is really worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set set = new HashSet();
set.add(2);
set.add(4);
...
m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), set);
```

Slightly better (from [here](http://blog.firdau.si/2010/07/01/java-tips-initializing-collection/)):

```
m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), new HashSet(Arrays.asList(1, 2)));
```

You can modify the set like this:

```
m.get(new TwoIntClass(5, 3)).add(6);
```

Comment: the last piece of code will generate a NullPointerException, see my comment

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: You can't say it "will generate a NullPointerException" when you don't know that `TwoIntClass` doesn't have a proper `equals` and `hashCode`. This example obviously assumes it does, which is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @ColinD, ... although worth mentioning nevertheless

Answer (score 4):

You have to be sure that the related `Set` is instantiated and inserted into the `Map` before doing anything. You could use something like

```
public void safeInsert(TwoIntClass tic, Integer element)
{
  if (!map.contains(tic))
    map.put(tic, new HashSet<Integer>());

  map.get(tic).add(element);
}
```

Mind that you can't use directly `Set` since it's an interface, so choose an actual implementation (eg. `HashSet`)

With Java8 every thing become easier:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(tic, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(element);
```

Comment: If you're working in a multi-threaded environment, safeInsert is only safe if its synchronized, or similar.  (synchronized block, etc.)  Otherwise there is a risk of replacing an exsiting Set with another, and losing the values stored in it.

Comment: noone never spoke about a multi-threaded environment :) In that case there is the utility `public static Set synchronizedSet(Set s)` that can be used to build up a synchronized Set and `public static Map synchronizedMap(Map m)` for the outer map

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a [SetMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) instead. This saves you from having to think about creating the sets yourself.

```
SetMultimap<TwoIntClass, Integer> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
TwoIntClass twoInts = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);
int num = 7;
multimap.put(twoInts, num);

Set<Integer> set = multimap.get(twoInts); // set contains 7

multimap.put(twoInts, 8);
multimap.put(twoInts, 9); // set now contains 7, 8 and 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the set first, add the item, and then put the set in the map.  There is no good way to initialize a set inline in Java.  (This may change when java 7 comes out.)

```
int num = 7;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(num);
m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), set);
```

Comment: But what if I want to do following m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), ?? how to put num inside Set ??);
change num; m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), ?? how to put num inside Set ??);
change num; m.put(new TwoIntClass(5, 3), ?? how to put num inside Set ??);

Answer (score 1):

Each time you want to put something in the set, you need to check if the set already exists, and create the set if it does not.  ie:

```
int num = 7;
TwoIntClass twoInt = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);
Set<Integer> intSet = m.get(twoInt);
if(num == null) {
  intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
  intSet.put(twoInt, intSet);
}
intSet.add(num);
```

There's a perfect abstraction over this in google's guava libraries called [SetMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) that you should consider using, especially if this is a repeated pattern in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 7;
TwoIntClass twoInts = new TwoIntClass(5, 3);
m.put(twoInts, new HashSet<Integer>());
m.get(twoInts).add(num);
```